# Show only first and last xAxis label in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, label, axis

I would like to display only the first and the last label on my xAxis. This would give enough of a »frame« for the user. However, I don't succeed in it. I am working with a synchronized chart, which can be found [here](https://graphs-test.unepgrid.ch/graph_global_atmosphere_800000_3.php). Is the second and third »column« of (smaller) graphs, I am targeting at.

I tried to work with »startOnTick« and »endOnTick«, but it won't do it.

```
    xAxis: {
      crosshair: true,
      events: {
        setExtremes: syncExtremes
      },
      visible: i === 1,
      showFirstlabel: true,
      showLastlabel: true,
      startOnTick: true,
      endOnTick: true,
      labels: {
        step: 500,
        format: '{value}'
      }
    },
```

What is the correct way to force Highcharts to display only first and last label?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/oxgdbu02/10/) is a short fiddle (don't know why the line does not appear; it shows the values with mouseover...).

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can use the **xAxis.labels.formatter** callback to show wanted ticks:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m2Ln8sdg/

```
    xAxis: {
    tickAmount: 10,
        labels: {
        formatter() {
        if(this.isFirst || this.isLast) {
            return this.value
        } else {
            return ''
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

- If you want to have more control about it (like hide label and tick) you can use the **load** callback method and proper logic to hide/show ticks:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fbcdskmv/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this;

        for (let i in chart.xAxis[0].ticks) {
            //hide all
          chart.xAxis[0].ticks[i].label.hide()
          chart.xAxis[0].ticks[i].mark.hide()
                    // show first and last tick
          if (chart.xAxis[0].ticks[i].isFirst || chart.xAxis[0].ticks[i].isLast) {
            chart.xAxis[0].ticks[i].mark.show()
            chart.xAxis[0].ticks[i].label.show()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

- Or use the tickPositioner callback to achieve it: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Thanks for that, although this yet doesn't work for me. It seems that Highcharts wants to oppress »round« numbers for the xAxis start and end. I set up a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/y4av2p8m/7/) that doesn't succeed with the above code to force the chart to display the first and last year of the data set.

Comment: Hm, I think that in your case using the tickPositions could be a good solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wz15t6ru/

Comment: Ha, ok, needed a bit more, as it treats the data in an array: `tickPositions: [dataset.data[0][0], dataset.data[dataset.data.length - 1][0]]`. Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are good, but i just wanted to show another approach which works just fine.

In my styling i do this;

```
.highcharts-xaxis-labels > text:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing up [@luftikus143](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983776/luftikus143) and [@Sebastian Wędzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10522842/sebastian-w%c4%99dzel) comments:

```js
const data = [
    ['Jan 2020', 167],
    ['Feb 2020', 170],
    ['Mar 2020', 172]
];

xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  tickPositions: [0, data.length - 1]
}
```

Will output only the first and last labels. [@martinethyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6383204/martinethyl)'s workaround answer might need some extra tweaks specially if you have multiple data points. Suggestions (might not work well with smaller media types):

```js
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
        rotation: 0,
        x: 5, // Optional: moves labels along the x-axis
        style: {
          textOverflow: 'none', // Removes ellipsis
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap', // Gets the label text in one line
        },
      },
```